# Найти самое длинное слово из строки

Tags: php

Что нужно поправить в моём скрипте, чтобы он искал 3 самых длинных слова в строке?

```
<?php
$text = 'раз четыре шестьдесят сорок пользователь он автомобиль номер';
$arr = explode(" ", $text);
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    $max = $arr[0];
    if(strlen($arr[$i]) > strlen($max)){

        $max = $arr[$i];
      }
    }
echo $max;
?>
```

Сейчас он просто выводит слово **номер**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример кода, надеюсь ознакомитесь с используемыми функциями и доработаете до желаемого результата.

```
$text = 'раз четыре шестьдесят сорок пользователь он автомобиль номер';
$arr = array_flip(explode(' ', $text));

// определяем длину
foreach ($arr as $word => $length) {
    $arr[$word] = mb_strlen($word);
}

// сортируем
asort($arr);

// последние 3 элемента
$result = array_slice($arr, -3, 3);
```

---

P.S.

Для определения длины, к сожалению, всё ещё приходится использовать [`mbstring`](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.mbstring.php)

Comment: оно же и без mb сработает. Просто strlen($word)

Comment: @Sven, как бы не true так делать. Хотя дело ваше =)

Answer (score 3):

Это предложение

```
$max = $arr[0];
```

следует поместить перед циклом. Иначе при каждой итерации каждое следующее слово сравнивается с первым словом.

Например,

```
$max = $arr[0];
for ($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
....
```

Comment: точно((...спасибо вам!

Comment: @Sven Не за что. Спрашивайте еще, если только мои ответы не будут удалять это хамье, местные модераторы,, которые удаляют ответы, идущие вразрез с их личным мнением.:)

Comment: ок, а если мы хотим узнать три самых длинных слова со строки этой, что можно дописать в код?

Comment: @Sven Можете создать массив из трех элементов, то есть первых трех слов строки,  и каждое следующее слово в строке сравнивать с элементами этого массива.

Comment: А можно без создания ещё одного массива? Просто добавить в код логику такую, что вывести 3 длинных самых слова.

Comment: @Sven В любом случае вам надо хранить где-то эти три самых длинных слова. Вы можете объявить три отдельные переменные. Суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: ок, допусти создаю массив с тремя словами, и как сравнивать их потом чтобы вместо них массив заполнился тремя самыми длинными словами из того массива? Лучше бы сразу скриптом показать если не трудно

Comment: @Sven Поместите первые три слова в массив по возрастанию или убываю. А затем каждое следующее слово можете даже последовательно сравнивать со словами в этом массиве, и если оно больше какого-то из имеющихся слов, то вставить его в массив, а меньшее слово удалить из массива.

Comment: пробовал, но у меня одинаковые слова вставились самые длинные в новый массив при сравнении, получилось : пользователь пользователь пользователь

Answer (score 0):

Вы на каждую итерацию перезаписываете $max, надо это делать до цикла

```php
<?php
$text = 'раз четыре шестьдесят сорок пользователь он автомобиль номер';
$arr = explode(" ", $text);
$max = $arr[0];
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    if(strlen($arr[$i]) > strlen($max)){
        $max = $arr[$i];
      }
    }
echo $max;
?>
```

Comment: спасибо! А что дописать в код, чтобы вывел 3 самых длинных слова?

Comment: То что описал Vlad from Moscow - с массивом - абсолютно верно. Можно либо добавлять в массив слово, если оно длиннее какого-либо из трёх, а затем самое короткое удалять, либо просто заменять самое короткое при том же условии. В последнем случае об изменении размера массива думать совсем не придётся.